# How can I append an array with result of each iteration within a for-loop in python?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I append an array with result of each iteration within a for-loop?

```
data = np.array([])
for sheet in sheets:
    result = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name = sheet,usecols="Q").dropna()
    result = result.values.tolist()
    result = result[1:]
    print(result)
```

If `print(result)` returns:

```
[1 , 2 , 3]

[4 , 5 , 6]

[7 , 8 , 9]
```

Then `print(data)` would look like this:

```
[[1 , 2 , 3],
 [4 , 5 , 6]
 [7 , 8 , 9]]
```

Comment: Make a list, append to it in the loop, call np.concatenate after the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([])  # Initialize an empty array

for sheet in sheets:
    result = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name=sheet, usecols="Q").dropna()
    result = result.values.tolist()
    result = result[1:]
    print(result)
    
    if len(data) == 0:
        data = np.array(result)  # Assign the first result directly to the data array
    else:
        data = np.append(data, result, axis=0)  # Append subsequent results to the data array
        
print(data)
```

Comment: This is very close. It comes out as [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]] rather than [[1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]. For some reason it seems like there was data loss as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy-vstack) to add a result as new row in numpy 2d array "data"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([])  # Initialize an empty array

for sheet in sheets:
    result = pd.read_excel(file_loc, sheet_name=sheet, usecols="Q").dropna()
    result = result.values.tolist()
    result = result[1:]
    print(result)

    if len(data) == 0:
        data = np.array(result)
else:
        data = np.vstack((data, result)) 
    
print(data)
```